# Crystal Reports - Trying to reset page numbers based on database field instead of group

Tags: crystal-reports, page-numbering

The issue that I am having is that I need to update page numbers based on data in the page header.  What I am trying to do is create a packing slip.  All the customer and order information is in the page header.  I need to reset the pages if there is more than one page for an order.  Right now, I am getting the number of N of M pages, but M is the total number of pages for all orders (example 1 of 18 pages, because there are 17 orders and one order is two pages long).  I want it to be 1 of 1 of there is only one order for the packing slips, but 1 of 2 if there is more than one page.  Does this make sense?  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is all of the displayed info contained in the page header? Nothing in the Details section, page footer, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are grouping by order number and starting a new page for each new order - by having checked the New Page After option in the Section Expert for the group footer - then you can check the option to Reset Page Number After in the Section Expert for the group footer.

Comment: That worked.  I made group one the order number and then reset page number after the group footer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Right Click the page footer in the left margin
- Click SECTION EXPERT
- Click the FORMULA BUTTON to the right of RESET PAGE NUMBER AFTER PageNumber = 2